# Saving context for every action

Tags: ios, core-data, ios9, magicalrecord

I have network park of my application which discovering devices in network and inserting into coredata through Magical Record. But this is happened on some other thread not main thread. Also I have UITableView with fetchresultcontroller which showing devices in table view. But only option how to let fetchRequestController now about my changes was, calling this:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

After every change. Missing I am something, or is this correct way how to make it?

Example:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    MyCDDevice * localDevice = [MyCDDevice MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
    [localDevice initFromDictionary:dictionary];
}];

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to save context as long as the App is running. Unless the App (might) crash (in which case you can save the context after some important entry). Saving the context should be done when the App goes to background and when the App is about to terminate. Excessive  writes to disk are not recommended.

Comment: Is your context a child of the main context?

Comment: @bauerMusic Thanks, I think same, but I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Wain good question I don't actually know. I take Magical record block call with local context and I think that local context is child from main context but can't confirm on 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save on every whole data operation, which is recommended by [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md). After `saveWithBlockAndWait:`, it is saved to persistent store, so there is no need to `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait`.